# How do i write this MYSQL statement in codeigniter?

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

How do i write this MYSQL statement in codeigniter ?

```
SELECT *, (UserPassword = $pass) AS UserPasswordMatch FROM all_users WHERE UserName = $Username
```

Comment: Do you mean using Activerecord? Because otherwise it's simply `$query = $this->db->query("[...]"); foreach( $query->result() as $row ) {[...]}`.

Comment: Yes Active Record.. Can any one help on this ? $this->db->query("[...]");  not working.....

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 option
as a normal query

```
$this->db->query("SELECT *, (UserPassword = $pass) AS UserPasswordMatch FROM all_users WHERE UserName = $Username");
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

using the active record of CI

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('all_users')->where(array('UserPassword' => $pass, 'UserName' => $Username));
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: First Option not working ?  but second option you have missed (UserPassword = $pass)  As UserPasswordMatch

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Champ '40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef' inconnu dans field list

SELECT *, (UserPassword = 40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef) AS UserPasswordMatch FROM all_users WHERE UserName = Johne

Comment: Hi, Sorry in the first option i wrote bad the sentence `$this->db->query("SELECT id, UserName, UserPassword AS UserPasswordMatch FROM all_users WHERE UserName = $Username AND UserPassword = $pass");
return $this->db->get()->result();`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

**First option** `without using active records`:

```
<?php
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM all_users WHERE UserName = '$Username' AND UserPassword = '$pass'");
return $this->db->get()->result();
?>
```

**Second option** using `active records`:

```
<?php
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('all_users');
$this->db->where('UserName', $Username);
$this->db->where('UserPassword', $pass);
return $this->db->get()->result();
?>
```